# Postgresql server instances

Tags: postgresql, multiple-instances

I have two server instances on the same host: a version 9.0 on port 5432 and a version 9.1 on port 5433. However when I run this windows script on the server I get a database "test" on the instance on port 5432:

```
C:\"Program Files\"PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\createdb --port=5433 --username=postgres test
```

I would suspect that it was created on the instance on port 5433. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a windows guy so I could be wrong but it looks like your encapsulation is wrong - your second quote is behind the \ which escapes it.

Postgres then isn't receiving the arguments correctly so it's falling back on defaults - EG port 5432.

Try:

`C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\createdb --port=5433 --username=postgres test`

Comment: Actually it has to be around the full filename: `"C:\Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\createdb"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not sure if that's a typo - but there you've got 3 quotes!
Should it be:
`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\createdb"`

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name and Will! Seems like you have a point there. Now I get an error - and not just nothing. If I write: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\createdb" --port=5433 --echo --username=postgres test I will get nothing. However when I write </br> start "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\createdb" --port=5433 --echo --username=postgres test I get this error: "Windows cannot find '--port=5433'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again". Two things pussle me - I thought that it didn't matter if you write "start" or not. And why can't it find port 5433?

Comment: I notice that I have "CEST FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist" in the log. If I create the database "postgres" on the 9.1 instance I can afterwards create the test-database on the 9.1 instance using --port=5433 in the script. I don't understand that - but that is apparently the cause of my script not working.

Comment: RE your comment Jul 5 8:18 - this is windows complaining - I'd guess it thinks `--port=5433` is a command - this is not a postgres error. 
RE your above comment, if you don't specify a database, postgres will attempt to connect / create a database with the same name as the user - in your case, postgres. I'm guessing this is what was happening. If you think my answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved. Thanks

Comment: To note, I always prefer to create databases and users in SQL, from within the psql client. I would guess that you would find it easier to as you're having difficulty with Windows parameter passing. From psql you'd just do:
`create database test owner postgres;`